# Polymer 3 - Google Maps files missing

Tags: google-maps, polymer-3.x

I am having the same issue as [Polymer 3 - Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785227/polymer-3-google-maps). After reading the above thread, I seem to be missing the two files `google-apis/google-maps-api.js` and `google-map-marker.js`.

In the hope it would download all the dependent files for Google Maps I issued these commands:

```
npm install @em-polymer/google-map
npm install google-maps
npm install
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Re-formatted the question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
import { html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
    import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map.js';
    import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map-marker.js';
    import { PageViewElement } from './page-view-element.js';

    // These are the shared styles needed by this element.
    import { SharedStyles } from './shared-styles.js';

    class MyView1 extends PageViewElement {
      render() {
        return html`
          ${SharedStyles}

          <section>
            <h2>Static page</h2>
            <p>This is a text-only page.</p>
            <p>It doesn't do anything other than display some static text.</p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <style>
            google-map {
              height: 600px;
            }
          </style>
          <google-map latitude="39.84143133531688" longitude="-117.4895451470561" api-key="1234"></google-map>
            </section>
        `;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Comment: what is the `PageViewElement` here? Iam using polymerElement.. Not litElement