# template getter must return HTMLTemplateElement error in polymer 3 google map

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-3.x

I am new in polymer 3 and getting the following errors:

```
template getter must return HTMLTemplateElement** and **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined.
```

Can someone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.
Please refer the attached image of code.

You can see on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N74Hu.png)

```
import { Polymer } from '@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js';
import { IronResizableBehavior } from '@polymer/iron-resizable-behavior/iron-resizable-behavior.js';
// import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map.js';
import '@em-polymer/google-apis/google-maps-api.js';
import '@em-polymer/google-map/google-map-marker.js';
import { html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
import { PageViewElement } from './page-view-element.js';

// These are the shared styles needed by this element.
import { SharedStyles } from './shared-styles.js';

class MyView1 extends PageViewElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      ${SharedStyles}
      <section>
        <style>
        google-map {
          height: 600px;
        }
      </style>

       <google-map latitude="39.84143133531688" longitude="-117.4895451470561" api-key="12345">
      <google-map-marker latitude="37.78" longitude="-122.4" draggable="true"></google-map-marker>
      </google-map>
        </section>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Comment: Can you check now? If you know the solution then pls help me on this.

Comment: Pls, add your code here. A photo is not available and editable.

Comment: Pls check it now.

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script> this line I kept in index.html page

Comment: Could you please help me on this, I tried everything but nothing is working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238103/polymer-3-google-maps-files-missing#new-answer

Comment: The above link also I didn't find any solution.

Comment: I had a problem with this package too so I switched to default google map api and wrote my own wrapping element

Comment: iam facing similar problem. I have done all possible googling of my knowledge. but no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785227/polymer-3-google-maps ... tried above link as well